# How can I do a health check on WCF hosts?

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

My organization has a large portfolio of complicated WCF services that are used internally. Infrequently (we're talking every few months), following one of IIS's 29-hour cycle reset events, one or more of these services will become unavailable. All attempts to invoke the service yield an exception deep in the service model, pertaining to trying to add faults while it's processing the contract. The only Google hits on that issue are the relevant source code, so it seems sufficiently occult that it's not worth the trouble to figure out what's going on, particularly as an IIS reset fixes the issue. Instead, we'd like to build a WebAPI health check method within the same server to ensure that all services are available, keeping in mind what we're monitoring is not our own systems but the health of WCF.

The first methodology we explored: All of our WCF services have a custom IServiceBehavior to initialize a variety of behaviors, so we added a segment to IServiceBehavior.Validate to register all endpoints that pass through it to a static list. The health check, when it gets polled, would then consist of using MetadataExchangeClient to fetch the metadata for each registered endpoint, with any failures get reported back as the system probably needing a reset. This worked great in artificial test scenarios, but two concerns cropped up:

1. Given that the scenario we're looking to prevent is specifically right after IIS doing a self reset, based only on the stack trace that we have it's difficult to tell if IServiceBehavior.Validate would actually have been called to register the service before WCF explodes.
2. Metadata fetching is disabled on production, so it's moot regardless.

It is within the realm of possibility to modify each service contract to add an empty health check operation, and have our loop instead invoke that on each endpoint. There are a lot of services though, and we'd prefer to avoid modifying them if we can. Is there some smarter way for the server to validate that each service is currently capable of returning, without modifying the services themselves or relying on metadata?

Comment: `only Google hits on that issue are the relevant source code, so it seems sufficiently occult that it's not worth the trouble to figure out what's going on` Seems figuring out what's going on is easier than what you want

Comment: Given that it's an ambiguous null pointer exception twelve frames deep in MS internal code, all invoked by the framework rather than us, and there's no material out there even remotely related to the relevant functions or classes, I'm not sure I agree.